# python, how to add matrix to the exist txt file

Tags: python, matrix, save

```
np.savetxt('workfile.txt',X,header='fist matrix',footer='\n')
f = open('workfile.txt', 'a')
f.write('# New slice\n')
f.close()
```

in this way, I can save the matrix X in a txt, and add the # New slice to the end
but what if I want to add Y to the bottom of the file behind X?

```
f = open('workfile.txt', 'a')
np.savetxt(f,Y,header='second matrix',footer='\n')
```

these sentences couldn't work, it shows that
TypeError: must be str, not bytes